# How to find out which modes (object, edit, weight paint, pose etc) is activated using Blender's Python API?

Tags: python, scripting, object-mode

There are buttons for switching to *object mode, edit mode, pose mode* and others. How to make sure which of these modes is active using Blender's Python API? Any information would help! Preferably with at least a small example of two simple buttons. For example, layers I managed to do on. off. But layers are not suitable. I will be very glad to your tips. Thank you very much! [image]

Comment: In earlier versions, or later with developer extras checked in user _`prefs > interface > display`_, you can right click on UI elements and view source.  My guess (as I don't have Avatar tools whatever addon) is they are booleans that when toggled update the mode, and unset the previous.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current activated mode with the following:

```
bpy.context.active_object.mode
```

This will print things like `OBJECT, EDIT, WEIGHT_PAINT, POSE` etc